# (duplicate) cassandra.bat is not able to run scripts and throwing error

Tags: cassandra

PS C:\Windows\system32> Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force
Set-ExecutionPolicy : Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy successfully, but the setting is overridden by a policy defined at a more specific scope.  Due to the override, your shell will retain its current effective
execution policy of Restricted. Type "Get-ExecutionPolicy -List" to view your execution policy settings. For more information please see "Get-Help Set-ExecutionPolicy".
At line:1 char:1

- Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy], SecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionPolicyOverride,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPolicyCommand
  ```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that Stack Overflow is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Comment: This is a duplicate question which has already been answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68703749/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68951404/. Cheers!